# Match until the first occurance of a symbol

Tags: regex, bash, non-greedy

Suppose we have a file containing lines of the following form (but **the number of #'s is not fixed**, and the length of fields is not fixed)

```sql
as#dviu#cvm#ud
```

For the above line, `.*#` matches `as#dviu#cvm#` (i.e. it goes as far as possible). How to match until the first occurrence of `#`? (i.e. match only `as#`)

Comment: Use `s="${s#*#}"` if you need to get `dviu#cvm#`, no need for a regex.

Comment: Can you call `grep -E` from your script ? If so you can get the use of non-greedy constructs. This is very important, there is almost nothing you can do with antiquated engines that don't support lazy operators.

Comment: @sln I needed the pattern for `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[^#]`, instead of `.`, to match anything except a `#`.